# Error 500 with ASP.NET Core (POST, PUT and DELETE)

Tags: asp.net-core

Good day all,

I have just implemented a REST API in ASP.NET MVC Core. GET works just fine but when I try to test POST, PUT and DELETE I am getting the same error:

```
{System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.}
```

Could anyone help me with hints how to avoid this error?

Comment: Did you add [HttpPost] on top of the function?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: are you testing this using VS2017 / IIS Express? or is it deployed on a server?

Comment: Yes, VS2017 / IIS Express, even deployment on the IIS on the other machine does give the same error.

Comment: did you test the http endpoint? if this works, then there is problem with the certificate of your localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I found out that I need to install SSL certificate - can be made using MakeCert.exe.